# node_modules/cypress/types not found

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm facing the below issue when trying to add the below for intellisense under `jsconfig.json` file.
Could you please help me to avoid this issue.

**Cypress Version:** 8.5.0

```
{
  "include": ["./node_modules/cypress", "cypress/**/*.js"]
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you install it with npm?

Comment: Yes I installed with npm.

Comment: run the following command in your project directory `npm list --depth=0` and see if it lists cypress

Comment: Yes it lists cypress@8.5.0

Comment: It seems to be a bug with the configuration shown on the Cypress documentation. References: [issue 1](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-documentation/issues/3075) [issue 2](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-documentation/issues/3063)